# Python basic program understanding

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to understand this program but can't get my head around it. Could anyone suggest where i'm going wrong?

```
def mult(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    rest = mult(a, b - 1)
    value = a + rest
    return value

print("3 * 2 = ", mult(3, 2))
```

In the above Python Script,

- The line print("3 * 2 = ", mult(3, 2)) is run
- The Mult function is called
- In the Mult Function b == 2 so the if condition return FALSE
- The Line rest = Mult(a, b -1) is next and calls the Mult function again on new values     (3,1)
- In the Mult Function b == 1 so the if condition return FALSE
- The Line rest = Mult(a, b -1) is next and calls the Mult function again on new values  (3,0)
- In the Mult Function b == 0 so the if condition return TRUE
- The value 0 is returned by the if condtion
- The program Prints "3 * 2 = 0"?

I followed your comments and put this together to make it easier to follow
[image: How to read]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your understanding lies with where the call to `mult(3, 0)` returns *to*. That call does not return to the line `print...`, it returns to the line `rest = mult(a, b-1)`. So then `value = a + rest` will result in `value` having the value of 3 + 0 = 3. Then the `return value` line will return to `rest = mult(a, b-1)` again. When it hits `return value` again, that is when it will return to the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a call-stack in your step-by-step-list: when the `b == 0` the function `mult` returns to the place where it was last called, that was the line `rest = ...` and not the line `print ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mult` recursively, and it returns to `rest`, so you will be updating that value each time you come back from the function. A few print statements might help clear up what is going on.

```
def mult(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        print "b = 0"
        return 0
    rest = mult(a, b - 1)
    value = a + rest
    print "rest", rest, "value", value
    return value

mult(3,2)
```

Output

```
b = 0
rest 0 value 3
rest 3 value 6
6
```